# Performing functions on array items in a single line

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$fruits = "lemon
    orange
banana
apple
    pear";

$fruits_a = explode("\n", $fruits);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fruits_a); $i++)
{
    $fruits_a[$i] = trim($fruits_a[$i]);
}
$fruits = implode(" ", $fruits_a);

echo $fruits;
?>
```

Is it possible to convert this (from explode to implode) into a single line ?
In python it would just be `fruits = " ".join(x.strip() for x in fruits.split("\n"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fruits = implode(
    ' ',
    array_map(
        'trim',
        explode("\n", $fruits)
    )
);
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I was going through the docs and came across array_map but couldn't put it together. I was thinking in terms of list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is

```
$fruits = implode(' ', array_map('trim', explode('\n', $fruits)));
```

Comment: @F4r-20 Ya..i forgot that..Thats why i deleted my answer. Now it is complete

Comment: Escape characters need to be in double quotes. I.e. `"\n"`